# Submit for Review - iTunes Connect App Store

Tags: ios

Is it possible between December 22-29 submit an app for Review? Because in my case this button "Submit for Review" appears disabled.

Thanks!

Comment: No, you have to wait until 29/12. they close ituneconnect at this time every year

Comment: They are on a christmas / winter break.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will wait until 29/12

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about programming.

Comment: no need for down voting anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact Apple announces annual winter `iTunes Connect` downtime slated for December 22-29.

[image: Calendar]

[See more about it.](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12102015a)